# My karma unit test executed but not stopping itself (using grunt)

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, karma-runner

I am running Karma to execute unit test cases using Grunt. It is running perfectly well, but the Karma process is not getting stopped automatically after test execution completion. No error/no log. Following are details on config and grunt file.

**karma-config.js**

```
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        // base path, that will be used to resolve files and exclude
        basePath: './../../../../',
        // frameworks to use
        frameworks: ['jasmine'],
        // generate js files from html templates
        preprocessors: {
            'ThemeLibrary/client/templates/categoryview/Category.html': 'ng-html2js'
        },
        // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
        files: [
            //Note: Order of file listing does matter therefore loading using * may cause issue
            //Load external libraries 
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/others/underscore-min_1.6.0.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.min-1.9.1.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/angularjs/angular-resource.min.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/angularjs/angular-route.min.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/angularjs/keypress.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/vendor/angularjs/truncate.js',
            'Test/unit/client/lib/angularjs/angular-mocks.js',
            'Test/unit/client/lib/jasmin/JasminHelper.js',
            //Load application library used by code.
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/utilities/JavascriptExtension.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/App.js',
            //Load directives HTML templates
            'ThemeLibrary/client/templates/categoryview/Category.html',
            //Load application source code which needs to be tested
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/utilities/*.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/controllers/*.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/services/*.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/factories/*.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/factories/implementation/*.js',
            'ThemeLibrary/client/js/application/directives/categoryview/Category.js',
            //Load test data            
            'Test/unit/client/testdata/*.js',
            'Test/unit/client/js/mock/*.js',
            //Test files
            'Test/unit/client/js/application/utilities/*.js',
            'Test/unit/client/js/application/controllers/*.js',
            'Test/unit/client/js/application/services/*.js',
            'Test/unit/client/js/application/factories/implementation/*.js',
            'Test/unit/client/js/application/factories/*.js',
            //'Test/unit/client/js/application/directives/categoryview/Category.test.js'
        ],
        // list of files to exclude
        exclude: [
        ],
        // test results reporter to use
        reporters: ['progress'],
        // web server port
        port: 9101,
        // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
        colors: true,
        // level of logging
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
        autoWatch: true,
        // Start these browsers
        browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
        // If browser does not capture in given timeout [ms], kill it
        captureTimeout: 60000,
        // Continuous Integration mode
        // if true, it capture browsers, run tests and exit
        singleRun: false,
        ngHtml2JsPreprocessor: {
            'moduleName': 'Templates',
            stripPrefix: '.*/ThemeLibrary/client',
            // Function that transforms the path to look exactly like you have it in templateUrl in your Angular code    
            cacheIdFromPath: function(filepath) {

                //return filepath.match(/\/templates\/categoryview\/.*\.html/);
                //return filepath.match('/templates/categoryview/Category.html');
                //return 'ThemeLibrary/client'+filepath;
                return filepath;
                 //return 'ThemeLibrary/client/templates/categoryview/Category.html';

            }
        }
    });
};
```

**Gruntfile.js**

```
/**
 * New node file
 */
module.exports = function(grunt){

    //globalConfig and paths which will used in the grunt script

    var config={

            srcFolderName: 'src',
            distFolderName: 'dist',
            appFileName: 'server.js',
            nodeModuleFolderName: 'node_modules',
                        testSourceFolderName: 'src-test',
                        testDestFolderName: 'Test',
            //change this command based on project requirement
            apiDocCommand:'apidoc -i src/server -o apidoc',
            npmInstallCommand: 'npm install --prefix ./dist/<%= pkg.name %>/node_modules'

    }

    //init
    grunt.initConfig({
        config:config,
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        copy: {

            //copy all source files to distribution folder
            sourceFiles: {
              cwd: '<%= config.srcFolderName %>',
              src: [ '**' ],
              dest: '<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>',
              expand: true
            },
            //copy main app file to dist folder
            mainAppFile: {
                src: '<%= config.appFileName %>',
                dest: '<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/<%= config.appFileName %>'
            },
            copyPackage:{
                src: 'package.json',
                dest: '<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/package.json'
            },
            //copy all source test files to distribution folder
            testFiles: {
              cwd: '<%= config.testSourceFolderName %>',
              src: [ '**' ],
              dest: '<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= config.testDestFolderName %>',
              expand: true
            }
          },
          clean : {
              build : {
                  src : [ '<%=config.distFolderName%>/','apidoc/' ]
              },
              pkgJson : {
                  src : ['<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/package.json']
              }
          },
          uglify: {
              serverCode:{
                  files: [{
                      expand:true,
                      cwd:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/server',
                      src:'**/*.js',
                      dest:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/server'
                  }]
              },
              clientCode:{
                  files: [{
                      expand:true,
                      cwd:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/client/js/application',
                      src:'**/*.js',
                      dest:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/client/js/application'
                  }]
              },
              mainAppFile: {
                  files: {
                       '<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/<%= config.appFileName %>':['<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/<%= config.appFileName %>']
                  }
              }
          },
          jshint:{
              serverCode:{
                  files:[{
                      expand:true,
                      cwd:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/server',
                      src:'**/*.js'
                  }]
              },
              clientCode:{
                  files: [{
                      expand:true,
                      cwd:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= pkg.name %>/client/js/application',
                      src:'**/*.js'
                  }]
              },
                  clientTestCode:{
                  files: [{
                      expand:true,
                      cwd:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= config.testDestFolderName %>/unit/client/js',
                      src:'**/*.js'
                  }]
              },
                  serverTestCode:{
                  files: [{
                      expand:true,
                      cwd:'<%= config.distFolderName %>/<%= config.testDestFolderName %>/server',
                      src:'**/*.js'
                  }]
              }
          },
          //mocha is used to automate unit testing of server side nodejs/express code.
          simplemocha: {
            options: {
                globals: ['expect'],
                timeout: 3000,
                ignoreLeaks: false,
                ui: 'bdd',
                reporter: 'tap'
            },
            all: { src: ['dist/Test/unit/server/**/*.js'] }
        },
        //karma is used to automate unit testing of client side angular/javascript test cases writtin in jasmine.
        karma: {
            unit: {
                configFile: 'dist/Test/unit/client/config/karma.conf.js',
                background: false
            }
        },
        protractor: {
                    options: {
                          configFile: "protractor-config.js", //your protractor config file
                          keepAlive: true, // If false, the grunt process stops when the test fails.
                          noColor: false, // If true, protractor will not use colors in its output.
                          args: {
                              // Arguments passed to the command
                          }
                      },
                    chrome: {
                        options: {
                              args: {
                                    browser: "chrome"
                              }
                          }
                    },
                    safari: {
                        options: {
                            args: {
                                browser: "safari"
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    firefox: {
                        options: {
                            args: {
                                browser: "firefox"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
         exec: {
                  generateAPIDoc : {
                      command: '<%= config.apiDocCommand %>'
                  },
                  buildDependencies :{
                      command: '<%= config.npmInstallCommand %>'
                  }
          }
    });

    // load our tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-copy');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-clean');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-simple-mocha');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-karma');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-protractor-runner');
    //for running executables
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-exec');

    grunt.registerTask('start-server', 'Start a custom web server', function() {
        grunt.log.writeln('Started web server on port 3000');
        require('./dist/ThemeLibrary/server.js');
    });

    //register the tasks
    grunt.registerTask('build',
            'Compiles all of the assets and copies the files to the build directory for Dev', 
            [ 'clean:build', 'clean:pkgJson','copy','exec:buildDependencies','jshint','exec:generateAPIDoc','uglify:serverCode','uglify:clientCode','uglify:mainAppFile','simplemocha','start-server', 'karma:unit']
    );
    grunt.registerTask('build-dev',
            'Only copies the source files for Dev', 
            [ 'copy:sourceFiles','copy:mainAppFile', 'copy:testFiles', 'jshint', 'simplemocha','start-server','karma:unit']
    );
};
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "ThemeLibrary",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "install": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update --standalone",
        "start": "node ./dist/ThemeLibrary/server.js",
        "start": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager start",
        "start": "node ./node_modules/protractor/bin/protractor ./dist/Test/integration/config/protractor-config.js"

    },
    "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://devops-tools.pearson.com/stash/projects/PTL/repos/pxe_theme_library/browse/ThemeLibrary"
  },
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "*",
        "body-parser": "*",
        "connect-busboy": "*",
        "cookie-parser": "*",
        "express-session": "*",
        "morgan": "*",
        "ejs": "*",
        "bcrypt-nodejs": "*",
        "mongodb": "*",
        "mongoskin": "*",
        "connect-flash": "*",
        "string": "*"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "grunt": "*",
        "chai": "*",
        "mocha": "*",
        "karma": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-copy": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-clean": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-uglify": "*",
        "grunt-contrib-jshint": "*",
        "grunt-simple-mocha": "*",
        "grunt-exec": "*",
        "karma-script-launcher": "*",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "*",
        "karma-firefox-launcher": "*",
        "karma-ie-launcher": "*",
        "karma-jasmine": "*",
        "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "*",
        "karma-story-reporter": "*",
        "grunt-karma": "*",
        "grunt-cli": "*",
        "karma-sauce-launcher": "*",
        "phantomjs": "*",
        "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "*",
        "node-inspector": "*",
        "protractor": "0.22.0",
        "grunt-protractor-runner": "*"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to set "singleRun" to true. Otherwise it will watch your files and run again on any changes.

Comment: Thanks :-) I was having this problem since last two weeks and couldn't figure out myself. It worked :-)

Comment: one small problem though....it is also killing the node server started using 'start-server' task. Is there any way to exit from karma task but keep node server up.

Comment: you would need to have the start-server process running in a separate process/terminal.

Comment: Thanks. I am also facing similar problem to start webdriverjs & protractor using grunt. I have posted separate thread. Please see if you can help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582435/running-webdriver-start-and-protractor-start-using-grunt-and-protractor-is-not-s